# How to create a customized report/dashboard in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, google-analytics-4

I need to create a custom report/dashboard/view in Google Analytics 4 (not UA) with

- the most viewed pages of the week and month
- the total amount of users and views of week and month
- the total amount of two different conversions of day, week and month

That shouldn't be a bigger issue in UA but I am totally lost with the new GA 4 UI and behaviour and can neither find anything on the documentation. Could someone please give me a starting point on that?